# How can I make it so only users who are admins can post articles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

The user model has a attribute :admin which can be true or false. I want to make a validation so only users with the admin = true can post articles or see the "New article" button in the view.

I am using the devise gem

Controller (articles_controller.rb) :

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /articles
  # GET /articles.json
  def index
    @articles = Article.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 4) 
  end

  # GET /articles/1
  # GET /articles/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /articles/new
  def new
    @article = current_user.articles.build
  end

  # GET /articles/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /articles
  # POST /articles.json
  def create
    @article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /articles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /articles/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.update(article_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /articles/1
  # DELETE /articles/1.json
  def destroy
    @article.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to articles_url, notice: 'Article was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
    end
end
```

Model (article.rb):

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments


  validates :title, length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates :title, uniqueness: true, uniqueness: { message: "This article title has already been posted."}
  validates :body, length: { minimum: 15 }
end
```

Model (user.rb):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
    validates_uniqueness_of :username 
  has_many :articles
  has_many :comments 

end
```

Schema :

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160320222854) do

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "article_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "comments", ["article_id"], name: "index_comments_on_article_id"
  add_index "comments", ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id"

  create_table "contacts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.text     "message"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username",               default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
    t.boolean  "admin",                  default: false
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
  end

  add_index "users", ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

view /articles (index.html.erb):

```
 <div class="row">
    <!-- Blog article Content Column -->
    <div class="col-lg-8">
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
        <!-- Blog article -->

        <!-- Title -->
        <h4 style="font-size: 45.5px;"><%= link_to article.title, article %></h4>
                        <!-- Date/Time -->
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> 
        <%= time_ago_in_words(article.created_at) %>
        </p>


        <!-- Author -->
        <p>
             Article By:<strong>  <%=  article.user.username %></strong>
        </p>

        <hr>

        <% end %>

<%= link_to "New article", new_article_path, class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>

    </div>



<!-- paginate -->

<%= will_paginate @articles %>

<br />
```

Thanks in advance to all the wonderful people here willing to lend a helping hand.

Comment: Can you update your view file also

Comment: Yes, I added the view file.

Comment: For better user roles support you can use Pundit or CanCanCan gems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a filter method in Application Controller

```
def admin_access
  render(text: 'Unauthorised') and return unless current_user.admin
end
```

And use this in Atricles controller or any other place where it is required

```
before_filter :admin_access, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

And in the views, check if user is admin

```
<% if current_user.admin %>
  # new/edit/delete links
<% end %>
```

Even though, not showing the link in the view solves the problem, It is always better to have proper authorisation logic in the server side.

Answer (score 0):

in the controller

```
def new
  if current_user.admin
    @article = current_user.articles.build
  else
    redirect_to root_path and return #somewhere you want to redirect
  end
end
```

in the view

```
<% if current_user.admin %>
  <%= link_to "New article", new_article_path, class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score -1):

To Show the `New Article` link to the only Admin. Add condition to your `link_to` tag. This will only hide the link.

```
<%= link_to "New article", new_article_path, class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" if current_user.admin? %>
```

Suppose if you want Admin Users only create a New Article. Then you need to implement authorization in your application. Try `cancancan` gem

For the [docs](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) and [video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan?view=asciicast)

Comment: Just hiding the link doesn't prevent the user from typing the URL `users/new` or `users/123/edit` into the browser's address bar.

Comment: I know already  that is the reason I mention both scenarios. :)

Comment: "can post articles or see the "New article" button in the view" in the question  make to answer like this.

Comment: thank you both this was the answer I was looking for, I will fix the routes next to prevent that.